# Is Mean Squared Error Loss function a good loss function for continuous variables $0 < x < 1$

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, objective-functions

Suppose I am utilising a neural network to predict the next state, $s'$ based on the current $(s, a)$ pairs.

all my neural network inputs are between 0 and 1 and the loss function for this network is defined as the mean squared error of the **Difference** between the current state and next state. Because the variables are all between 0 and 1, the MSE difference between the **actual difference** and **predicted difference** is smaller than the actual difference.

Suppose the difference in next state and current state for $s \in R^2$ is $[0.4,0.5]$ and the neural network outputs a difference of $[0.2,0.4]$. The mean squared loss is therefore 0.05 $(0.2^2 + 0.1^2) = 0.05$ whereas the neural network does not really predict the next state very well due to a difference of $(0.2, 0.1)$.

Although whichever loss function is used does not matter, It was deceiving to think that despite the loss function outputting low values, it is mainly due to the **squared** term that keeps the value small.

Is Mean Squared Error loss function still a good loss function to be used here ?

Comment: Mean is usually done over batch size, not elements of the output vector. Besides, nothing is stopping you from having $n$ outputs nodes and having separate loss function for each element, that would be equal to summing the loss of all elements